# Can't connect to SQL Server from WCF service but I can from Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, wcf, sql-server-2008, iis-6, database-connection

I'm trying to connect a .NET Framework 4.0 WCF REST service on an IIS6 to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with this connection string:

```
<add name="EReportEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/EReportModel.csdl|res://*/EReportModel.ssdl|res://*/EReportModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=localhost;Database=ADM;User Id=sa;Password=XXXXXXXX;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But I can't. I get:

```
Event Type: Failure Audit
Event Source:   MSSQLSERVER
Event Category: (4)
Event ID:   18456
Date:       10/19/2012
Time:       10:47:48 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   UNILEVER
Description:
Login failed for user 'sa'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 18 48 00 00 0e 00 00 00   .H......
0008: 09 00 00 00 55 00 4e 00   ....U.N.
0010: 49 00 4c 00 45 00 56 00   I.L.E.V.
0018: 45 00 52 00 00 00 07 00   E.R.....
0020: 00 00 6d 00 61 00 73 00   ..m.a.s.
0028: 74 00 65 00 72 00 00 00   t.e.r...
```

But, if I use sa user to login on SQL Server Management Studio I can login.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a connection string for **Entity Framework** - are you using EF to talk to SQL Server from your WCF service?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Entity Framework.

Comment: And is your database really on the same server as your IIS ? You're using `Server=localhost` in your connection string.

Comment: Yes, both are in the same machine. System administrator is telling me now that it is a problem with "surface exposure"...

Comment: Yes, I know. I've asked about this and the DB administrator said me that there is no problem. :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use other connection string variant at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

It's hardly surprising that your WCF services can't connect, given that your connection string points to `localhost`.

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/EReportModel.csdl|res://*/EReportModel.ssdl|res://*/EReportModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;Server=localhost;
Database=ADM;
. . .
```

What I often recommend is to wrap your WCF services in a `try..catch`, and if things go wrong, append the connection string to the error message, to check that your services *are* using the right connection string.

(I've had times where my `web.config` has contained several connection strings, but my Entity Framework/LINQ to SQL have decided to use the wrong one.  This'll pinpoint such cases.)

For example, here's the code I would use, for a simple WCF service:

```
public List<wsCustomer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    NorthwindDataContext dc = null;
    try
    {
        dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
        List<wsCustomer> results = new List<wsCustomer>();
        foreach (Customer cust in dc.Customers)
        {
            results.Add(new wsCustomer()
            {
                CustomerID = cust.CustomerID,
                CompanyName = cust.CompanyName,
                City = cust.City
            });
        }
        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
        response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        response.StatusDescription = ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "") + "  " + dc.Connection.ConnectionString;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using this code, if something goes wrong, you can see the SQL Server error and which server/database it was attempting to use.

[image: Error message]

More details here:
[WCF Deployment and troubleshooting](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page5.htm)